# Git make new branch of cloned project into distinct project

Tags: git

Hi I have a a project which I am happy with. So I cloned it with the intention of splitting it off and making significant changes which would lead to a new project. I really wanted to keep this separate from the original repo. So I did some work on a new branch called 'branch-a'. I setup an different remote repo and pushed the commits of 'branch-a'. I now want to merge into master branch and push.

My questions are: do I now have two master branches? One for the original project and one for the new project? Can I merge 'branch-a' into master without affecting the original project I cloned from?

I'm sure this is all straight forward- just need to get some advice. Also is there a better workflow for doing what I am doing (forking)?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I now have two `master` branches? One for the original project and one for the new project?

Yes. One `master` branch per repo.

> Can I merge '`branch-a`' into `master` without affecting the original project I cloned from?

Yes. And you will still be able to push '`branch-a`' from the first repo into the second repo.

Merging a branch into another does nothing for the branch source (the one you are merging into said other branch like `master`).
It add a new commit on master with two parent (unless the merge is a fast-forward one, in which case, `master HEAD` is simply moved to `a-branch HEAD`, again without touching `a-branch` at all)